# Excel VBA: How to convert ranges to numbers and get output in a column as list

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert ranges to list of numbers. All alphabets from the input need to be omitted and only to consider integers, coma and en-dash. The output list need to be in 5 digits, so need to add a prefix of "0"s if less than 5 digits.

Example: Input "Group 10,20-22,31" , "Group 00022-00024" & "Group 35" given in Column A need to be converted to an output list in column B (as mentioned below).

```
      |    Column A [INPUT]    |  Column B [OUTPUT]  | 
Row 1    Group 10,20-22,31           00010
Row 2    Group 00022-00024           00020
Row 3    Group 35                    00021
Row 4                                00022
Row 5                                00023
Row 6                                00024 
Row 7                                00031
Row 8                                00035
```

I took help from function mentioned in the below link and but was only able to expand ranges between first and last integers but this also includes the numbers in between, which are not available in the input.
[Excel: Convert Range to Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254919/excel-convert-range-to-numbers)

Can you help to modify the the function mentioned in the above link? Or suggest a new function?

I'm new to Stackoverflow & VBA. Apologies for the change in input and hope it is clear now.

Comment: What code have you done so far? Please paste it.

Comment: You might get some ideas from a related post [Create list of unique elements and display group mempbership parsed by commas and en-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111013/create-list-of-unique-elements-and-display-group-membership-parsed-by-commas-and). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54072881/edit) your question and include relevant code you've tried so far (even pseudo code). A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps illustrating a concrete issue and getting an answer here @JP2020 :-)

Comment: You can also do this with a worksheet formula. What version of Excel? And is this example truly representative?

Answer (score 0):

Since you reference a function in your link, I will reuse it in my proposed solution.

```
Function SplitStr(xx As String) As String
    valu = Split(xx, ",")
    Stri = ""
    For Each nn In valu
        If InStr(1, nn, "-") > 0 Then
            For i = Left(nn, InStr(1, nn, "-") - 1) To Right(nn, Len(nn) - InStr(1, nn, "-"))
                If Stri <> "" Then
                    Stri = Stri & "," & i
                Else
                    Stri = i
                End If
            Next
        Else
            If Stri <> "" Then
                Stri = Stri & "," & Trim(nn)
            Else
                Stri = Trim(nn)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SplitStr = Stri
End Function
```

Here is my solution, see comments for the explanation:

```
Sub Explode()
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim arrValue() As String
Dim currentRow As Long, i As Integer

' Take the string result of the function SplitStr and assign it to an array
arrValue = Split(SplitStr(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value), ",")

' Clear B column
ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Clear

' B row counter
currentRow = 1

' Loop through each values
For i = arrValue(LBound(arrValue())) To arrValue(UBound(arrValue()))

    ' Assign the value to B column
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & currentRow).Value = i

    'advance to next "B" row
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Run Explode() Sub and see your B column populated with range of values indicated in Range("A1").